# Dialog content not centered horizontally on Droid X

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a Dialog, setting a content view with two Buttons, and displaying it. Oddly enough, even though I properly centered it vertically and horizontally, on the Droid X extra blank space appears at the top and on the right side.

I discovered the top is reserved for the Dialog title; even when that title is blank, the space is kept empty. The workaround there is easy enough--I set a title.

The right side, however, baffles me. When I test the same app on other devices it works beautifully; the Droid X, however, keeps the right side of the screen empty. When the root layout of my Dialog's layout has a width of match_parent or fill_parent, it does not extend to that empty area. However, if I manually set a fixed large width, it does extend as far as it needs to--no more empty space on the right side. That's hardly an ideal solution though.

Does anyone know how to get around this Droid X layout quirk so Dialogs do not have that empty space on the right side?

Comment: I know that this is old (and this is not really an answer), but I'm seeing similar problems with a custom dialog (all phones).  No solution yet, but the extra space on the right looks suspiciously like the same amount of space that the scrollbar would take.

Please post if you found a solution or hack.

Comment: No solution yet, I'm afraid! Hopefully someone will find an answer one day and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I found that if I change the margin and/or padding sizes, suddenly the Dialog becomes centered!  For example: margins of 4dp creates an offset.  But making the top, bottom, left, and right margins all larger and different makes the problem go away.

This sort of behavior generally means one of two things: There's a bug in how the layout is drawn, or I have a gross misunderstanding of how these things work.  Both seem equally likely.

So my answer is: play with the margin (and padding) numbers.  It's possible that you can find something that both works and is aesthetically pleasing.

Sorry, I know this answer sucks.  So it goes.

Comment: I'm happy to take this as an answer, at least until something better comes along--and I bet it's a bug, but maybe someone else will be able to say differently